# Angular NGXS store has null root

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

I am trying to create a basic store in my angular application and am following the tutorial but when I look at the store in Redux DevTools the store structure is Store > null > User rather than Store > User.

This may be an issue with the Redux Tools and NGXS but also when I try to use a selector to get the information out nothing comes back

This is my State Code (user.state.ts):

```
  @State<UserStateModel>({
      name: 'user',
      defaults: {
        user: null
      }
    })

    export class UpdateUser {
      static readonly type = '[User] Update User';
      constructor(public user: User) { }
    }

    export interface UserStateModel {
      user: User;
    }

    export class UserState {
      @Selector()
      public static user(state: UserStateModel): User {
        return state.user;
     }

    @Action(UpdateUser)
      updateUser(ctx: StateContext<UserStateModel>, action: User) {
      const state = ctx.getState();
      console.log('update user action', action);
      ctx.patchState({
        user: action
      });
    }
```

Here is my user model (user.model.ts):

```
export class User {
  userId?: string;
  username?: string;
  password?: string;
  token?: string;
}
```

And finally where I am trying to us the selector (ts):

```
  user$: Observable<User>;

  @Select(UserState.user) userSelect$: Observable<User>;
  constructor(private summonerService: SummonerService, private store: Store) {
    this.user$ = this.store.select(state => state.user.user);
  }
```

(template)

```
<div>
  {{(this.user$ | async)?.userId}}
</div>
```

I get no errors on compile or runtime, the console log in the action shows the correct information and so does the store (apart from the null)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem or not, but the action method, updateUser, gets an UpdateUser as it's 2nd parameter, so your patch should be user: action.user

Comment: You were correct I was passing in the Object class rather than the Action class however when I changed that to be correct I still end up with the same as my store structure and the selectors not working

Comment: are you lazy loading by any chance can you share your project structure and app module ?

Comment: and also why are you not using `this.userSelect$ | async`. Try to log value in your component too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was due to copy pasting, but the `@State()` decorator should be attached to the class that represents the state. Not to one of the actions. Additionally, the action is of type `UpdateUser` not of type `User`. Hence, it should look like this:

```
export class UpdateUser {
  static readonly type = '[User] Update User';
  constructor(public user: User) { }
}

export interface UserStateModel {
  user: User;
}

// Decorator belongs here
@State<UserStateModel>({
  name: 'user',
  defaults: {
    user: null
  }
})
export class UserState {
  @Selector()
  public static user(state: UserStateModel): User {
    return state.user;
  }

  @Action(UpdateUser)
  updateUser(ctx: StateContext<UserStateModel>, action: UpdateUser) { // Changed Datatype
    const state = ctx.getState();
    console.log('update user action', action);
    ctx.patchState({
      user: action.user // Changed fromn action to action.user
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the app.module have you added your state into the `NgxsModule.forRoot()`?

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is having this issue, be sure to check that your decorator inside your `state.ts` file has an `@` before the `State`. This was my issue when the store had a null root when everything else was looking good.

Before:

```
State<MyStateModel>({
  name: 'statename',
  defaults: {
    ...
  },
  children: [...],
});
```

After:

```
@State<MyStateModel>({
  name: 'statename',
  defaults: {
    ...
  },
  children: [...],
})
```

You won't see an error since Typescript just thinks you're calling a function.